# after I used Component, this intellisense doesn't work. What is the problem?

Tags: components, intellisense

[image]

after I used Component, this intellisense doesn't work. What is the problem??

thank you for helping.

Comment: Sometimes vscode can get a little stuck for some reason, but... to get intellisense to pop up, try pressing Ctrl+Space (Cmd+Space on Mac). (Also, this is irrelevant, but to get better syntax highlighting, at the bottombar you can set the language to JavaScript React)

Comment: thank you. it's so helpful.